# How to display the search result set in Primefaces datatable lazyloading

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading, filtering

We are using Primefaces datatable lazyloading, inorder to display the search results (Eg: search a student). The Datatable works good as below...

Please click here to see the search result http://xomf.com/gdnrn

But, our need is to have a input fields and a find button. when we click the find button with some criteria provided in the input fields:

1.The datatable should render and

2.Lazy loading should carry the input filed values given, into the load method which is overriden from lazyDataModel

We are done with the 1 but struggling with 2.

The code which I'm currently working with find button is:

studentsearch result.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<div class="form_container">
    <p:panel header="Search Student">
        <h:form id="findStudent">
            <div class="attribute_row">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="span"
                    value="Student name" />
                <h:inputText styleClass="common_form_textbox_large"
                    value="Student name" />
            </div>
            <div class="attribute_row">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="span"
                    value="Agency Code" />
                <h:inputText styleClass="common_form_textbox_medium"
                    value="Agency Code" />
            </div>
            <div class="attribute_row">
                <h:commandButton styleClass="common_form_button margin_left"
                    id="showButton" value="Find"
                    action="#{StudentManagedBean.findAgency}">
                </h:commandButton>
            </div>
        </h:form>
        <h:form rendered="#{AgencyManagedBean.dataTableRenderValue}">
            <p:dataTable var="var1" value="#{StudentManagedBean.lazyModel}" 
                 paginator="true" rows="5" id="stuTable" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 lazy="true">
                 <p:column headerText="StudentRollNumber" sortBy="#{var1.rollNumber}" filterBy="#{var1.rollNumber}"  
                        filterMatchMode="exact">
                        <h:outputText value="#{var1.rollNumber}"
                            ></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                     <p:column headerText="StudentName" sortBy="#{var1.name}" filterBy="#{var1.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{var1.name}"
                            ></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="StudentRank" sortBy="#{var1.rank}" filterBy="#{var1.rank}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{var1.rank}" 
                            ></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="StudentDepartment" sortBy="#{var1.department}" filterBy="#{var1.department}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{var1.department}"
                            ></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think 'simple'... break down the problem... Step 1: pass the fields to a backing bean... Plain and simple... Step 2: The lazyDataModel is 'just' a class, you can always pass the fields of a backingbean to a lazyDateModel (assuming it is a field/property of the same bean), or if the lazyDataModel is a managedBean, you can always inject the backing bean with the fields... and step 3: use them in the load method in the lazyDataModel